# Cuda hangs on cudaDeviceSynchronize randomly

Tags: c, cuda, freeze

I have a piece of GPU code that has worked for a while.  I recently made a couple minor algorithmic changes, but they didn't touch the CUDA part.

I'm running production runs on a set of three Xeon machines, each with a 780 Ti in it.  Each run takes about three minutes to complete, but at this point there have been two cases (out of 5000) where the application has hung for hours (until killed).  Both were on the same machine.

The second time, I attached GDB to the running process, and got a backtrace that looks like

```
#0  0x00007fff077ffa01 in clock_gettime ()
#1  0x0000003e1ec03e46 in clock_gettime () from /lib64/librt.so.1
#2  0x00002b5b5e302a1e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcuda.so
#3  0x00002b5b5dca2294 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcuda.so
#4  0x00002b5b5dbbaa4f in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcuda.so
#5  0x00002b5b5dba8cda in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcuda.so
#6  0x00002b5b5db94c4f in cuCtxSynchronize () from /usr/lib64/libcuda.so
#7  0x000000000041cd8d in cudart::cudaApiDeviceSynchronize() ()
#8  0x0000000000441269 in cudaDeviceSynchronize ()
#9  0x0000000000408124 in main (argc=11, argv=0x7fff076fa1d8) at src/fraps3d.cu:200
```

I manually did a `frame 8; return;` to forcibly make it finish, which caused it to end up stuck on the next cudaDeviceSynchronize() call.  Doing it again got it stuck on the next synchronization call after that (every time with the same frames 0 through 8).  Extra strangely, the failure happened in the middle of the main loop, on the ~5000th time through.

After killing it, the next jobs starts and runs properly, so it doesn't appear to be a systemic failure of the execution host.

Any ideas about what could cause a random failure like this?

I'm compiling and running with V6.0.1, running with driver version 331.62.

Comment: Try updating the GPU driver to [331.89](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/76749/en-us)

Comment: I'll try updating the driver -- it's unfortunately difficult to check if it worked though, as it's a 1-in-a-million error.

Comment: Have you found any information about this problem? I am currently experiencing a similiar situation (using cuda toolkit v5.5). For me, trying different driver versions did not work.

Comment: @Thomas  Sadly, no.  It appears to be a card-specific problem affecting a few[not all] of the cards.  At some point I intend to find and RMA the problem cards; I *think* I remember seeing intermittent issues when trying cuda memtest.  As my primary load was many invocations of an program with a ~3 minute runtime, my temporary "solution" was just to use `timeout` to run it with a 5 minute time limit and abort/retry if that limit was hit.  I would suggest you try cuda memtest under various conditions (I had one that only error'd when cold), and see if that tells you anything interesting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seemed to be caused by some sort of  rare and difficult to reproduce hardware problem which lies outside of the scope of a [SO] question.

Comment: @talonmies, the problem is not rare. CUDA also hangs for me consistently on GeForce GTX 560 Ti. There are now 3 people with this problem with privilleges enough to comment. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Apparently, a call to `cudaSetDevice()` in the beginning of each CPU thread fixes the problem for me.

Comment: 3 yers later. GeForce GTX 1080. Driver Version: 384.81. Same situation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the problem code.  Without that, it's impossible for anybody else to reproduce and diagnose your problem.

Comment: I've recently run into this problem as well. I found this post by following the forum question here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/862612/cuda-programming-and-performance/synchronization-hangs-sporadically-after-kernel-launch/1. Maybe that will shed some light on the issue. Hope it helps; if I find out more I'll return.

Comment: I think I have a very similar problem, reported [here (with C stack traces)](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/issues/323). This is with TensorFlow. So far without solution.